# Visual Studio 2017 Web Essentials, while debug, auto-scroll to bottom

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, web-essentials, visual-studio-2017

I am developing ASP.NET WebForm in Visual Studio 2017, after installing Web Essentials 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebExtensionPack2017

I notice that every time I start my app and debugging in Chrome, after the page loaded completely, in 1 or 2 seconds, the page automatically scroll to bottom.

Anyone know why is this happening? Is there any settings that I can make to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem on VS15 enterprise.. what worked for me is disabling 'Browser Link'
[image]

Comment: Hey, Problem solved! Thank you very much for the sharing ;)